High probability with empty text tensorflow
I have a chatbot code
intense.json:
{"intents" : [

{"tag": "greetings",
"patterns": ["hi", "hello", "greetings"],
"responses": ["Hello!", "Hi!"]
},

{"tag": "name",
"patterns": ["whats your name", "who are you?"],
"responses": ["I`m a ChatBot"]
},


]}

training.py:
# importing the required modules.
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
#nltk.download('stopwords')
from keras.models import Sequential
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import tensorflow as tf
import codecs

#stop_words = set(stopwords.words('russian'))

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

# reading the json.intense file
intents = json.loads(codecs.open("intense.json", "r", "utf_8_sig").read())

# creating empty lists to store data
words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ["?", "!", ".", ","]
for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        # separating words from patterns
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)  # and adding them to words list

        # associating patterns with respective tags
        documents.append(((word_list), intent['tag']))

        # appending the tags to the class list
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])

        # storing the root words or lemma
words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)
         for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
words = sorted(set(words))

# saving the words and classes list to binary files
pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(classes, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))

# we need numerical values of the
# words because a neural network
# needs numerical values to work with
training = []
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)
for document in documents:
    bag = []
    word_patterns = document[0]
    word_patterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(
        word.lower()) for word in word_patterns]
    for word in words:
        bag.append(1) if word in word_patterns else bag.append(0)

    # making a copy of the output_empty
    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])
random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training, dtype=object)

# splitting the data
train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])

# creating a Sequential machine learning model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]), ),
                activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]),
                activation='softmax'))

# compiling the model
sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y),
                epochs=2000, batch_size=5, verbose=1)

# saving the model
model.save("chatbotmodel.h5", hist)

# print statement to show the
# successful training of the Chatbot model
print("Yay!")

main.py:
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import nltk
from keras.models import load_model
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import codecs
import time

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents = json.loads(codecs.open("intense.json", "r", "utf_8_sig").read())
words = pickle.load(open('words.pkl', 'rb'))
classes = pickle.load(open('classes.pkl', 'rb'))
model = load_model('chatbotmodel.h5')

def clean_up_sentences(sentence):
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)
                      for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words


def bagw(sentence):
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentences(sentence)
    bag = [0] * len(words)
    for w in sentence_words:
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if word == w:
                bag[i] = 1
    return np.array(bag)


def predict_class(sentence):
    bow = bagw(sentence)
    res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]
    ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25
    results = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res)
               if r > ERROR_THRESHOLD]
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = []
    for r in results:
        return_list.append({'intent': classes[r[0]],
                            'probability': str(r[1])})
        print(return_list)
        return return_list


def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
    try:
        tag = intents_list[0]['intent']
    except:
        return err
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    result = ""
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    else:
        result = "err" # NOT WORKING
    return result


print("Chatbot is up!")

while True:
    message = input("")
    ints = predict_class(message)
    result = []
    if ints != "cant": # NOT WORKING 2
        res = get_response(ints, intents)
        for i in range(len(res)):
            result.append([*res][i])
            print("".join(result), end='\r')
            time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2) / 20)
        print("\n")

The problem is that a simple grammatical error such as 'helo' and an empty string have the same probability, which is why the bot writes "Hello!" or "Hi!" for any unexpected question/blank string. How can I fix this? (so that the bot responds to an unexpected question with “error” and not “hello”)

Hi @Zailox To handle unexpected questions or inputs, you can modify your predict_class function to check if the highest probability is below a certain threshold. In your predict_class function, you have an ERROR_THRESHOLD set to 0.25. This means the model will predict an intent for any input with a probability greater than 0.25.Modify the get_response function to handle cases where predict_class doesn't return any intent. Currently, if ints is not "cant" (which seems like a placeholder), it assumes there's an intent and proceeds.
